# How do I use quick data entry to Scale to the 3D Cursor when using Normal Transformation Orientation?

Tags: modeling

[image: ScaletoZ]

I have a model that is turned at a 45 degree angle. I want to scale the selected faces to the 3D Cursor's position with the Normal Transformation Orientation selected using the shortcut S, Z, 0 enter. Z is the axis shown for the Normal Transformation Orientation that I want to scale along, but the operation is of course scaling along the world's Z axis. How do I change the behavior in Blender so that I can use the keyboard shortcuts for the Normal Transformation Orientation?

BTW...I know that I can use the Scale Transformation Manipulator and drag it in the direction I want and enter 0 to accomplish this task, but my question is specifically about using the S, Axis, 0 method in conjunction with the 3D Cursor's position for Normal Transformation Orientation.

Comment: Transform Orientations in the Properties Bar has an add + orientation button too, which is nice for averaging a view along odd planes or citing a normal for use later. Found that one later then I would have wanted

Comment: Thanks fairweather, I will play with that and see how it can help me in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply have to press the axis key (<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>) twice when performing the transformation.

For example, pressing <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> will scale everything to 0 along the 'Z' normal axis *if* 'Normal' transformation type is selected in the 3D view header:

[image]

Basically whatever transformation is selected in the header will be switched to when pressing the axis key twice.

Comment: Thanks Ray! I knew that was how "Local" transforms worked. I don't know why I didn't try that with Normal.